# How to give additional info to a brokerpod in akri, or start different brokerpods depending on the udev rule

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to start a custom brokerpod in akri depending on the udev rule and want to give the brokerpod the additional info from which udev rule it was started. I tried it like this, but this seems not to be working.

```
helm repo add akri-helm-charts https://project-akri.github.io/akri/
helm install akri akri-helm-charts/akri \
    $AKRI_HELM_CRICTL_CONFIGURATION \
    --set udev.discovery.enabled=true \
    --set udev.configuration.enabled=true \
    --set udev.configuration.name=akri-udev-video \
    --set udev.configuration.discoveryDetails.udevRules[0]='ATTR{product}=="AAAA"' \
    --set udev.configuration.brokerPod.image.repository[0]=nginx \
    --set udev.configuration.discoveryDetails.udevRules[1]='ATTR{product}=="BBBB"' \
    --set udev.configuration.brokerPod.image.repository[1]=nginx:1.24
```

This starts two akri instances I can see with kubectl get akrii but nginx as an example seems not to be running correctly. If I start it for only one rule I can enter the nginx container.

```
helm repo add akri-helm-charts https://project-akri.github.io/akri/
helm install akri akri-helm-charts/akri \
    $AKRI_HELM_CRICTL_CONFIGURATION \
    --set udev.discovery.enabled=true \
    --set udev.configuration.enabled=true \
    --set udev.configuration.name=akri-udev-video \
    --set udev.configuration.discoveryDetails.udevRules='ATTR{manufacturer}=="manufacturer_of_AAAA_and_BBBB"' \
    --set udev.configuration.brokerPod.image.repository=nginx
```

But the aim is to start different containers and also to give brokerProperties depending on the udev rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal of starting different custom brokerpods in Akri, depending on the udev rule, and passing additional information to these brokerpods, you will need to modify your [Helm chart](https://docs.akri.sh/user-guide/getting-started) configuration.
The key is to correctly set up the [udev configuration](https://github.com/squillace/akri/blob/20c53fadd445dcbfbb3c0a5f5bc641c03ccb8c96/docs/udev-configuration.md) in Akri to match specific devices based on [udev rules](https://github.com/squillace/akri/blob/20c53fadd445dcbfbb3c0a5f5bc641c03ccb8c96/docs/udev-configuration.md#choosing-a-udev-rule) and to customize the [brokerPod configuration](https://docs.akri.sh/development/debugging#installation-with-pod-brokers) accordingly.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                          Kubernetes Cluster                   |
|                                                               |
|   +-------------------+           +----------------------+    |
|   |  Akri Controller  |<----------|     Broker Pods      |    |
|   +-------------------+           +----------------------+    |
|              |                              |                 |
|              |    Discovers Devices         |                 |
|              |    Matching udev Rules  /----+----\            |
|              |                         |         |            |
|   +-------------------+      +-----------+     +------------+ |
|   |   udev Discovery  |----->| Broker A  |     | Broker B   | |
|   |    Configuration  |      +-----------+     +------------+ |
|   +-------------------+             |                |        |
|              |                      |                |        |
|              |    Matches Devices   |                |        |
|              |    Based on Rules    |                |        |
|   +-------------------+             |                |        |
|   |   udev Rule 1     |-------------+                |        |
|   |   udev Rule 2     |------------------------------+        |
|   +-------------------+                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

First, define multiple [udev configurations](https://docs.akri.sh/discovery-handlers/udev#udev-configuration-settings), each targeting a specific set of devices based on your udev rules. Each configuration should specify a different brokerPod to be deployed when devices matching its udev rule are discovered.

Then, customize brokerpod for each udev rule: for each udev configuration, specify a different brokerPod image or configuration. That makes sure different brokerpods are started based on the device they correspond to.

To pass additional information to the brokerpod, such as which udev rule triggered its start, you can use environment variables or other configuration methods supported by Kubernetes and Akri.

First, define multiple [udev configurations](https://docs.akri.sh/discovery-handlers/udev#udev-configuration-settings), each targeting a specific set of devices based on your udev rules. Each configuration should specify a different brokerPod to be deployed when devices matching its udev rule are discovered.

Then, customize brokerpod for each udev rule: for each udev configuration, specify a different brokerPod image or configuration. That makes sure different brokerpods are started based on the device they correspond to.

To pass additional information to the brokerpod, such as which udev rule triggered its start, you can use environment variables or other configuration methods supported by Kubernetes and Akri.

Your Helm chart needs to be adjusted to reflect these multiple configurations. That might look something like the following (simplified for illustration):

```yaml
udev:
    discovery:
    enabled: true
    configuration:
    - name: akri-udev-rule1
        discoveryDetails:
        udevRules: ['ATTR{product}=="AAAA"']
        brokerPod:
        image:
            repository: custom-image-for-rule1
    - name: akri-udev-rule2
        discoveryDetails:
        udevRules: ['ATTR{product}=="BBBB"']
        brokerPod:
        image:
            repository: custom-image-for-rule2
```

Deploy this modified Helm chart to your Kubernetes cluster. Akri will then deploy different brokerpods based on the devices it discovers that match the specified udev rules.

If the brokerpods are not running as expected, check the logs of the Akri controller and the brokerpods for any error messages. (`kubectl get pods`, `kubectl logs <broker-pod-name>`, `kubectl describe pod <broker-pod-name>`)

---

> The more important part now is even to give the environment variable, than it can even be the same brokerpod. And there I am still not sure how to pass for example something from the udev rule to the pod.

Passing specific information from a udev rule to a broker pod in Akri would involve a two-step process: first, capturing the necessary information within the udev rule, and second, transmitting this information to the broker pod, typically via environment variables.

To capture information in udev rule, use udev rule syntax to match and assign device attributes to environment variables.
Example of anudev rule that captures the `ATTR{product}` value:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{product}=="AAAA", ENV{MY_UDEV_ENV}="$attr{product}"
```

Then use Akri's configuration to pass the captured information from the udev rule to the broker pod. That is typically done by referencing the environment variable set in the udev rule within the broker pod's environment variable configuration.
Akri does not, however, seem to directly support dynamically passing custom environment variables from udev rules to broker pods. Akri's environment variables for broker pods are usually predefined and static in the Helm chart.

One possible workaround is to use a custom broker pod that can query the node or the Akri controller for the specific device information based on known static environment variables (like device ID or node name).
For instance, your broker pod could be a script or application that first reads a static environment variable to get the device ID or node name and then performs a query or lookup to find the corresponding udev information for that device.

A simplified example of setting a static environment variable in a broker pod configuration would be:
`yaml udev: configuration: - name: akri-udev-rule1 brokerPod: env: - name: STATIC_ENV value: "SomeStaticValue"` 
Your custom broker pod logic would then use `STATIC_ENV` to perform further actions or queries to obtain dynamic information.

```bash
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                      Kubernetes Cluster                   |
|                                                           |
|  +-------------------+        +----------------------+    |
|  |  Akri Controller  |        |     Broker Pods      |    |
|  +-------------------+        +----------------------+    |
|           |                              ^                |
|           |    Discovers Devices         |                |
|           |    Matching udev Rules       |                |
|           |                              |                |
|  +----------------------+                |                |
|  |   udev Discovery     |----------------|                |
|  |    Configuration     |                |                |
|  +----------------------+                |                |
|           |                              |                |
|           |    Matches Devices           |                |
|           |    Based on Rules            |                |
|  +----------------------+                |                |
|  |    udev Rule with    |----------------+                |
|  |  Captured Information|                                 |
|  +----------------------+                                 |
|           |                                               |
|           |    Environment Variable (Static)              |
|           |                                               |
|  +----------------------+                                 |
|  |   Custom Broker Pod  |                                 |
|  |      Logic (Script/  |                                 |
|  |     Application)     |                                 |
|  +----------------------+                                 |
|           ^                                               |
|           | Queries for Additional Info                   |
|           | Based on Static Env Variable                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Develop a custom broker pod application/script that uses the static environment variable to derive or fetch additional details.
That might involve querying the local system, the Kubernetes API, or other mechanisms to correlate the static information with dynamic details captured by the udev rule.

That approach requires a custom development effort on the broker pod side, as the dynamic passing of arbitrary udev rule-derived information to broker pods is not a native feature so far. The key is in the custom logic within the broker pod that can interpret or use static environment variables to discover more dynamic details about the device it is associated with.

---

Implementing a custom broker pod that uses static environment variables to retrieve additional device information in Akri involves creating a custom application or script within the broker pod. That custom logic is responsible for using the static environment variable to derive or fetch the dynamic information related to the device.

A conceptual implementation using a Python script as an example would be a script part of the custom broker pod's container image:

`broker_logic.py`:

```py
import os
import some_device_query_library  # Hypothetical library to query device info

def get_dynamic_device_info(static_env_var):
    # Logic to use static environment variable to find dynamic device information
    # That could involve querying the local system, Kubernetes API, etc.
    # For example, using a static device ID to find more details about the device
    device_id = static_env_var
    device_info = some_device_query_library.query_device_info(device_id)
    return device_info

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Retrieve the static environment variable
    static_env_var = os.getenv('STATIC_ENV', 'default_value')

    # Get dynamic device information
    dynamic_info = get_dynamic_device_info(static_env_var)
    
    # Implement your logic here using the dynamic device information
    print(f"Dynamic Device Info: {dynamic_info}")
```

the Dockerfile for the custom broker pod:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Copy the Python script into the container
COPY broker_logic.py /broker_logic.py

# Set the command to run the script
CMD ["python", "/broker_logic.py"]
```

Build the Docker image and push it to a container registry.

```bash
docker build -t my-custom-broker-image .
docker push my-custom-broker-image
```

Then reference the custom broker image in akri configuration:

```yaml
udev:
    configuration:
    - name: akri-udev-rule1
        brokerPod:
        image:
            repository: my-custom-broker-image
            tag: latest
        env:
            - name: STATIC_ENV
            value: "SomeStaticValue"
```

That assumes that the custom broker pod can retrieve additional information based on the static environment variable through some means (like querying the Kubernetes API, local system queries, etc.).
The actual implementation details will vary based on how the device information is exposed, and how it can be correlated with the static information available in the environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not that experienced with helm charts and did not get it to work right now.
But the more important part now is even to give the environment variable, than it can even be the same brokerpod. And there I am still not sure how to pass for example something from the udev rule to the pod.

Comment: @Klaus OK, I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the work you put into answering this. Yeah akri sets something like UDEV_DEVNODE und UDEV_DEVPATH, with this I can get the other information again in the started pod. Than this is the way I go. I thought there must be a way to do it the other way round.. I accepted your answer now, thanks.

Comment: Maybe I can use brokerproperties, but this is probably again for all udev rules I specify and I can't give different Properties for different rules..
     # brokerProperties is a map of properties that will be passed to any instances
      # created as a result of applying this udev configuration
       brokerProperties: